# Iterate through url using strings - python

Tags: python, nested-urls

I'm completely stuck with my code right now. First of all I try to retrieve all urls from a archive page of the volkskrant. This is the first step were I got struck. The url of one specific date looks as following: http://www.volkskrant.nl/archief/detail/01012016

The last numbers reflect the date and is the same for every page, so I came up with the idea to make strings for the day (DD) the month (MM) and the year(2016).

Next, I the links to the pages, directs me to a page with even more links of the articles I eventually want to get. I know how to get the URLS of one of the dates, but not for all. Eventually I need to scrape all text of the page, which I also can do for one page. Another problem is that I need to retrieve all articles on the next page as well, but I have no clue how to implement that in the code as well.

Basically, I have major troubles with iterating through links, especially with the use of strings in it. Hopefully, someone is able to help me out with this.

```
The code looks as following atm:
> Scraping archive of Volkskrant   
month=['01','02'.. etc]   
day =['01','02','03'.. etc]   
year=['2016']    
for x in month:
    for y in day:
        next_date= 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/archief/detail/'+str(y)+str(x)+str(year)

> getting links of one single date    
req=request.Request('http://www.volkskrant.nl/archief/detail/01012016', headers={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0"})    
archive=request.urlopen(req).read()    
archive=archive.decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore").replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")    
for link in archive:     
    links=re.findall(r'<article class="article article--extended".*?</article>', archive)    
url1= ''.join(map(str,links))    
for item in url1:    
    urls= re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'">]+)', url1)    


>go to next page and retrieve all links there    
nextpage=re.findall(r'<span class="pagination__item">.*?</span>', archive)     
nextp= ''.join(map(str,nextpage))     
for item in nextp:     
    next= re.findall (r'href=[\'"]?([^\'">]+)', nextp)[:1]    


> retrieving one article and scrape content     
req=request.Request('http://www.volkskrant.nl/politiek/pechtold-wil-d66-blijven-leiden~a4283833/', headers={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0"})     
tekst=request.urlopen(req).read()    
tekst=tekst.decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore").replace("\n"," ").replace("\t"," ")    

> scraping the introduction with Xpath as the regex was not applicable
tree=html.fromstring(request.urlopen(req).read().decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore"))     
artikel3=tree.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]/text()')    
... etc
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex to get the urls when you have lxml?

Comment: Ah I first started using html and then figured that it wasn't as effective for all things I wanted, thus I started using lxml. This is way more convenient indeed. The code is very helpful; I managed to complete the scraping by now.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the links including pagination and every day from Jan 1 to now:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now().date()
start = datetime(2016, 1, 1).date()

from lxml import html

base = "http://www.volkskrant.nl/archief/detail/{}"
def parse(url):
    # pagination__item
    xml = html.parse(url)
    links = xml.xpath("//li//article[@class='article article--extended']/a/@href")
    nxt_pag = xml.xpath("//span[@class='pagination__item']/a[@class='pager pager--next']/@href")
    yield links
    while True:
        xml = html.parse(nxt_pag[0])
        new = xml.xpath("//li//article[@class='article article--extended']/a/@href")
        yield new
        nxt_pag = xml.xpath("//span[@class='pagination__item']/a[@class='pager pager--next']/@href")
        if not nxt_pag:
            break


for day in range((now - start).days + 1):
    for links in parse(base.format(start.strftime("%m%d%Y"))):
        print(links)
    start += timedelta(days=1)
```

To get the text just parse each link:

```
from itertools import chain

for day in range((now - start).days + 1):
    for link in chain.from_iterable(parse(base.format(start.strftime("%m%d%Y")))):
        xml = html.parse(link)
        desc = (xml.xpath("//p[@itemprop='description']/text()"))
        paras = xml.xpath("//p[contains(@class,'article__body__paragraph')]/text()")
        print(desc)
        print(paras)
    start += timedelta(days=1)
```

Forst few results:

```
[u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWereldwijd is de jaarwisseling gemarkeerd door afgelaste massabijeenkomsten en de inzet van enorme aantallen politie-en legereenheden bij festiviteiten die wel plaatsvonden. In de Duitse stad M\xfcnchen werden twee stations tijdelijk gesloten na een tip van Franse en Amerikaanse inlichtingendiensten over dreigende aanslagen door de terreurgroep Islamitische Staat (IS).']
[u"Hoewel de Duitse autoriteiten op nieuwjaarsdag zeiden dat er geen sprake meer was van een acute dreiging, schetsten ze de toestand niettemin als precair. 'De situatie in Europa en Duitsland blijft ernstig in het nieuwe jaar', zei minister van Binnenlandse Zaken Thomas de Maizi\xe8re: Zijn Beierse collega Joachim Hermann sprak over een 'algemene, permanente dreiging'.", u"In Frankrijk werden 100 duizend agenten ingezet om aanslagen te voorkomen. Het traditionele vuurwerk in het centrum van Parijs was geannuleerd, maar niettemin verzamelden zich tienduizenden mensen op de Champs-\xc9lys\xe9es. Niet eerder waren er zoveel mensen bijeen sinds de Franse hoofdstad enkele weken geleden werd getroffen door een reeks aanslagen op openbare gelegenheden, waarbij 130 mensen om het leven kwamen. President Fran\xe7ois Hollande zei rekening te houden met nieuwe aanslagen. Frankrijk heeft volgens hem 'nog geen einde gemaakt aan de terreur'. ", u'In Belgi\xeb weren donderdag drie personen aangehouden die werden verdacht van het beramen van aanslagen rond de jaarwisseling. Ze zouden gericht zijn tegen de politie, militairen en bekende locaties in Brussel. Die dreiging was voor burgemeester van Brussel Yvan Mayeur aanleiding om het jaarlijkse vuurwerk in het centrum van de stad te elfder ure af te blazen. De drie verdachten zijn vrijdag na verhoor weer vrijgelaten.', 'Ook in steden als Moskou, Jakarta, Madrid en Sydney werden de gebruikelijke grootschalige vieringen van Oud en Nieuw afgelast of beperkt. In Moskou bleef het Rode Plein leeg, nadat het was afgegrendeld door veiligheidstroepen. ', u"'Het is geen geheim dat Moskou een potentieel doelwit is van terroristen,' zei burgemeester Sergej Sobyanin. Vrijdag werden honderden mensen twee treinstations in Moskou ge\xebvacueerd nadat de politie een tip had gekregen dat er explosieven werden geplaatst. Er werden echter geen explosieven aangetroffen. De autoriteiten gaven verder geen commentaar op de dreiging. ", "In New York verzamelden zich zo'n miljoen mensen op Times Square. Ze werden gadeslagen door 6.000 politiemensen, onder wie speciale anti-terreur-eenheden. In de stad Rochester in de staat New York werd een vuurwerkfeest afgelast vanwege terreurdreiging. Een 25-jarige man die eerder deze week werd opgepakt, zou plannen hebben gehad voor een aanslag op Oudejaarsavond. ", "Londen zette volgens Scotland Yard 3.000 ('alle beschikbare') politiemensen in om de festiviteiten in goede banen te leiden."]
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 'Al op haar 6de was Natalie Cole te horen op een kerstalbum van haar vader Nat King Cole. Ook haar eigen repertoire is onvergetelijk.']
["De grootste hit van de op oudjaarsdag op 65-jarige leeftijd overleden Natalie Cole was Unforgettable uit 1991, een duet met haar vader, de legendarische jazz-zanger Nat King Cole. Cole was al in 1965 overleden en Unforgettable was dan ook een virtueel duet, waarbij zij haar partij toevoegde aan een nummer dat hij oorspronkelijk in 1951 had opgenomen. De ode aan haar vader op het gelijknamige album, verder gevuld met klassieke Cole-covers, leverde haar een aantal Grammy's op (waaronder het Album van het jaar) en een van de best verkochte albums van het jaar - ze zou tijdens haar leven 30 miljoen albums verkopen: 'Het is al een shock dat het nummer op de radio wordt gespeeld', zei ze in een interview in die tijd. "]
["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMet Alan Alda was hij drie jaar lang het populairste tv-duo van de jaren '70."]
["De op 82-jarige leeftijd overleden Wayne Rogers speelde alleen in de eerste drie seizoenen mee, voordat M.A.S.H. de populairste Amerikaanse televisieserie werd, en ver voordat er in 1983 een recordaantal van 125 miljoen Amerikanen voor de buis zat om de laatste aflevering te zien. Toch zal hij altijd bekend blijven als legerchirurg John 'Trapper' McIntyre, onafscheidelijk van zijn cynische vriend en collega Hawkeye Pierce (Alan Alda).", ' Rogers kreeg ruzie met de producenten en vertrok na drie seizoenen, een besluit waarvan hij later zou zeggen dat hij er spijt van had, toen hij merkte hoe populair de serie werd. ']
["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAngela Merkel is ervan overtuigd dat de ruim een miljoen vluchtelingen die in 2015 naar Duitsland kwamen 'een kans voor morgen' zijn. Dat zei de Duitse kanselier in haar nieuwjaarstoespraak."]
["De vluchtelingen kunnen Duitsland zowel economische als maatschappelijke voorspoed brengen, zei Merkel, wetend dat veel Duitsers grote vraagtekens plaatsen bij dit idee en haar mantra 'wir schaffen das'.", "Natuurlijk, zei de kanselier, zal de integratie van zoveel mensen nog 'tijd, kracht en geld' kosten. Maar meer dan deze kleine handreiking kregen haar critici niet. In de eerste plaats, zei ze, wilde Merkel de mensen bedanken die 'zoveel meer dan hun plicht' hebben gedaan om vluchtelingen op de vangen, vrijwillig of professioneel.", " De twee buitenparlementaire voortrekkers in het protest tegen vluchtelingen, Pegida en de AfD, noemde Merkel niet bij naam. Toch waarschuwde ze de Duitsers er wel voor. Net als vorig jaar riep ze de bevolking degenen die 'het Duits-zijn alleen voor zichzelf willen houden' niet te volgen omdat ze kou en zelfs haat in hun hart dragen.", 'De toespraak werd in de Duitse media tamelijk positief ontvangen. De voornaamste kritiek was dat Merkel nergens concreet werd. Ze noemde geen maatregelen om Duitsland inderdaad op termijn van de vluchtelingen te laten profiteren.', u" In de EU wint Merkel het vaak op uithoudingsvermogen, zeggen Brussel-watchers. Het lijkt erop dat ze dat ze een soortgelijke tactiek nu in haar eigen land toepast met betrekking tot haar omstreden vluchtelingenbeleid. Merkel blijft ostentatief trouw aan haar eigen idee\xebn. Dat benadrukte ze in deze nieuwjaarstoespraak door letterlijk een passage uit die van een jaar geleden te citeren, waarin ze zei dat het 'vanzelfsprekend is dat we de mensen opnemen die toevlucht bij ons zoeken.'", "Daarmee toont Merkel zich bewust van haar macht. De vrouw die een maand geleden door Time Magazine werd verkozen tot de persoon van het jaar had namelijk ook tegemoet kunnen komen aan haar critici door te benadrukken hoeveel strenger het Duitse vluchtelingenbeleid dit jaar tussen de regels door toch geworden is: er wordt gecontroleerd aan de grens en vluchtelingen van de Balkan krijgen zelden meer een verblijfsvergunning. Bovendien onderschreef Merkels eigen partij het CDU op het jongste partijcongres het streven 'de toestroom van vluchtelingen merkbaar te verminderen'.", " Maar Merkel refereerde aan niets van dat alles. 'Wir schaffen das', zei ze opnieuw, 'omdat Duitsland een sterk land is.'"]
["\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOndanks duizenden meldingen van vernieling, overlast, brandstichting, openlijke geweldpleging en geweld tegen hulpverleningsdiensten is oud en nieuw volgens de politie 'rustiger verlopen dan vorig jaar'. De politie registreerde in heel Nederland 7.566 incidenten, tegen 8.218 vorig jaar en 17 procent minder aanhoudingen."]
["Meer agenten dan vorig jaar, 78 om 59, werden het slachtoffer van fysiek geweld. 'Het verbale geweld tegen de politie zakte echter met bijna een kwart', meldt de politie. Het aantal vuurwerkincidenten is 'opvallend' gedaald (met 21 procent) en de politie registreerde minder brandstichtingen. ", "De brandweer rukte ruim 4.500 keer uit, bijna honderd keer vaker dan vorig jaar. Wel meldt de brandweer dat ze dit jaar met meer verbaal en fysiek geweld te maken hebben gehad. In verschillende plaatsen werden blussende brandweerlieden bekogeld. In Amersfoort ging een stoeptegel door de ruit van een brandweerauto. 'Onacceptabel en respectloos', stelt Brandweer Nederland in een verklaring. ", "Ook het Openbaar Ministerie (OM) meldt een rustiger jaarwisseling dan vorig jaar. Uit een eerste inventarisatie bleek dat de politie 276 mensen bij het OM aanleverde wegens, meestal, een geweldsmisdrijf. Vorig jaar waren dit er nog 377. Acht personen moeten maandag bij de 'supersnelrechter' voorkomen. ", 'In de vier grote steden meldden brandweer, politie en ambulancemedewerkers dat ze het ongeveer net zo druk hadden als rond de vorige jaarwisseling. De politie van Amsterdam hield 157 personen aan rondom 648 incidenten.', 'In Utrecht werden 22 jonge mensen aangehouden. Daar had vooral de brandweer het veel drukker dan vorig jaar, vooral met autobranden. Twee jongens raakten zwaargewond toen ze van een balkon op de tweede etage vielen tijdens een oud en nieuw-feestje. In Veenendaal kwam een 57-jarige man om het leven door brand in zijn woning.', "In Den Haag reed een 25-jarige automobilist in op een groep mensen. Twee mensen moesten naar het ziekenhuis. De beginnende autobestuurder zou ruim zes keer meer alcohol hebben gedronken dan toegestaan. 'Den Haag heeft een drukke, maar feestelijke jaarwisseling beleefd', aldus burgemeester Jozias van Aartsen. 'Uiteindelijk hebben we niet meer problemen gehad dan op een drukke stapavond met veel mensen op de been.'", "In Rotterdam rukten brandweer en ambulances ruim 700 keer uit. Veertien auto's gingen in vlammen op. Hulpverleners die op een brand af waren gekomen, werden door omstanders bestookt met vuurwerk. De politie moest daar het publiek op afstand houden en voerde charges uit. Ook in het Brabantse Oss zijn hulpverleners belaagd met vuurwerk. Agenten werden geslagen en bekogeld, de politie sprak van 'een geweldsexplosie'. In Tilburg en in Amersfoort hebben jongeren met vuurwerk, flessen en stenen gegooid naar brandweer- en politiemensen die aan het werk waren.", 'In Leeuwarden werden ook agenten met vuurwerk bestookt. De politie schermde daar een krat illegaal zeer zwaar vuurwerk af totdat medewerkers van de Explosieven Opruimingsdienst Defensie (EOD) het onschadelijk hadden gemaakt.', 'In Zaandam raakte een twintigjarige man zwaargewond toen zijn zelfgemaakte vuurwerkbom tot ontploffing kwam. In Ridderkerk ontplofte een vuurwerkbom waarbij een slachtoffer naar het ziekenhuis moest.', 'Volgens de vuurwerkbarometer van het Openbaar Ministerie heeft de politie 45.268 kilo illegaal vuurwerk in beslag genomen, ruim 5.000 kilo meer dan vorig jaar. Nederlanders hebben in 2015 met naar schatting 65 miljoen euro, weer meer geld uitgegeven aan vuurwerk, aldus de Belangenvereniging Pyrotechniek Nederland.', 'Steeds meer gemeenten stellen vuurwerkvrije gebieden in, al dan niet in combinatie met een eigen, gemeentelijke vuurwerkshow. Omdat ook vuurwerkregels strenger zijn geworden, rukt de brandweer sinds de vorige jaarwisseling een kwart minder vaak uit.', u"Volgens burgemeester Pieter Broertjes van Hilversum werkt de vuurwerkvrije zone in zijn stad. Er is \xe9\xe9n bekeuring uitgedeeld. De gemeente organiseerde voor het derde opeenvolgende jaar een eigen vuurwerkevenement: 'Dit lijkt me toch het model voor de toekomst', zegt Broertjes."]
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 'Alles wat iemand opschrijft is in zekere zin uiteindelijk autobiografisch.']
[u"Bij Nabokov is dat extra interessant want tegelijkertijd met zijn (indertijd en nog steeds) spraakmakende Lolita schreef hij Pnin: Timofej Pnin is een stuntelige, Russische professor aan een Amerikaanse universiteit, een voor het Sovjet-regime gevluchte aristocratische vijftiger die moeite bl\xedjft houden met de Engelse taal, een onknappe, excentrieke, lieve blunderaar die achter zijn rug wordt uitgelachen door zijn collega's en gefascineerd toekijkt hoe gymschoenen ronddraaien in de wasmachine, een man als een'gebarsten pingpongballetje' met een naam als een 'absurd ontploffinkje'; in alle opzichten is die goeie Pnin, hoewel \xf3\xf3k een wetenschapper uit het oude Europa die \xf3\xf3k dol is op zijn stiefkind (maar dan in het nette), het tegenovergestelde van Humbert Humbert, de knappe, charmante en slinkse slechterik uit Lolita. "]
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 'Het beste voornemen voor 2016: hou een dagboek bij. Niet alleen zijn alle deskundigen het erover eens dat het goed is alles van je af te schrijven, het levert ook schitterende literatuur op. Wie een dagboek bijhoudt, voert een gesprek met de belangrijkste persoon in zijn leven: zichzelf.']
[u"'Ik voer hierbij het zo dikwijls voorgenomen plan uit een dagboek bij te houden', noteerde de Franse schilder Eug\xe8ne Delacroix op 13 september 1822. 'Het is mijn grootste wens om niet uit het oog te verliezen dat ik voor mijzelf alleen schrijf; naar ik hoop zal ik daardoor waarheidsgetrouw zijn. Daar word ik een beter mens van. "]
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 'Warenhuis V&D heeft het einde van 2015 niet gehaald. Op oudjaar werd formeel het faillissement aangevraagd van V&D, inclusief de restaurantketen La Place. Maar de belangrijkste vraag die voor vrijwel elke betrokkene boven de markt blijft hangen: is dit het einde van V&D, of start het bedrijf in 2016 gewoon weer door? Zo ja: wat gebeurt er dan met het personeel? En met de schuldeisers die nog rekeningen hebben uitstaan bij het warenhuis?']
['V&D topman John van der Ent laat over het antwoord op die vraag geen twijfel bestaan. In de brief die hij op Oudejaarsdag aan zijn personeel stuurde, schrijft hij met klem dat dit niet het einde betekent van V&D of La Place. ']
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'Als 2014 het jaar was waarin Vladimir Poetin de Europese ordening vloerde met de annexatie van de Krim en de oorlog in Oost-Oekra\xefne, dan was 2015 het jaar waarin Poetin weer salonf\xe4hig werd. Het kan verkeren.']
[u'Ook in MH17-land Nederland, getuige de overweldigende stilte over de recente deal die onder meer Shell-topman Ben van Beurden sloot met Gazprom, de energiepoot van het Kremlin. Getuige ook de handtekeningen van 400 duizend Nederlanders voor een raadgevend referendum over de vraag of we in EU-kader de banden met Oekra\xefne moeten versterken en daarmee het door Poetin belaagde land een kans op overleving moeten gunnen - of dat we het behalve militair ook politiek en economisch voor de leeuwen moeten gooien, zodat wij meer aandacht kunnen besteden aan onze eigen sores.', " De 'long game', het strategische geduld en de beginselvaste aanpak die bondskanselier Merkel bepleitte, moest al snel opboksen tegen concurrerende dreigingen, nieuwe prioriteiten en oude economische instincten.", u" President Poetin zelf zat ook niet stil. Met zijn militaire interventie in Syri\xeb ten gunste van Assad eiste hij een centrale rol op en dwong hij westerse leiders weer met hem te praten. Hij leek het initiatief te hebben overgenomen van de weifelende VS-president Obama, die hem nota bene had weggezet als leider van slechts 'een regionale macht'.", "De grote energiebedrijven spelen hun eigen 'long game'. Daarin is business as usual de ultieme wijsheid; worden politiek netelige kwesties met dooddoeners platgeslagen; en lijken ceo's speciaal geschoold om zich aan de voeten te werpen van potentaten uit energierijke landen. It's a dirty job, but somebody's got to do it, nietwaar?", u' Dus hoewel de westerse sancties intact bleven, de Fransen een streep haalden door de verkoop van twee oorlogsschepen aan Rusland en Itali\xeb en andere Zuid-Europese landen de torpedering van de Russische pijpleiding South Stream slikten, gingen grote Duitse energiebedrijven en Shell opnieuw in zee met Gazprom voor de bouw van een tweede gaspijpleiding van Rusland naar Europa: Nordstream 2.', u" Centraal-Europese EU-landen stuurden hierover een klaagbrief, maar kregen nul op het rekest. Ik herinner me nog de woede, in november 2007, van de woordvoerder van Gasunie, toen ik bij het nieuws van de ondertekening van de Nederlandse deelname aan Nordstream I in deze krant gewag had durven maken van het feit dat deze pijpleiding 'omstreden' was. Inderdaad was er toen ook al geen discussie in Nederland over de deelname aan deze Russische wurgtactiek van de directe buurlanden, voorop gasdoorvoerland Oekra\xefne.", u'Ophef ontstond evenmin toen Marcel Kramer, de Gasunietopman die ons aansloot op Poetins strategische pijpleidingstelsel, voor zijn moeite beloond werd met een benoeming tot bestuursvoorzitter van South Stream. Gerhard Schr\xf6der raakte in eigen land tenminste nog in opspraak voor zijn opzichtige opstapje van het kanselierschap naar een goed betaald luxebaantje bij Nordstream. Niet in Nederland natuurlijk, waar de oud-minister van transport Camiel Eurlings probleemloos KLM-directeur kan worden.', u' Zo passeerde Nordstream ons land in stilte. Maar dat was v\xf3\xf3r de Russische inval in Oekra\xefne, voor het neerschieten van passagiersvliegtuig MH17 vanuit pro-Russisch gebied en voor de afkondiging vanuit Brussel van een zogeheten Energie Unie, waarvan een essentieel onderdeel is het streven naar diversificatie van energiebronnen.', " Dat Nordstream 2 dus ook in alle rust regering en media in Nederland passeert, is op zijn minst opmerkelijk. Of is dat onderdeel van het grote, stilzwijgende complot dat hier heerst sinds de 17de eeuw en dat we zo graag onze 'koopmansgeest' noemen? Kort samengevat: we hebben wel andere dan economische consideraties, maar niet als het om geld gaat.", u' Tegen deze achtergrond is het alarmerend dat juist in onze winderige delta - gelegen in de strategische luwte van grotere buurlanden en waar het hemd altijd nader is dan de rok - de komende maanden een laatste besluit valt over de ratificatie van het associatieakkoord met Oekra\xefne.', u'Politici, die dezer dagen hun wijsheid vooral uit peilingen proberen te halen, hebben al besloten dat het oordeel van het volk beslissend is. En geheel indachtig onze fascinatie met onszelf gaat ook in dit referendum de aandacht vooral uit naar de wijze waarop dit stijlmiddel al dan niet een nuttige aanvulling is op ons democratisch bestel. Er wordt vooral gedebatteerd over de voors en tegens van het adviserend referendum, veel minder over de vraag die voor ligt: of het associatieverdrag met Oekra\xefne wel onze steun verdient.', " Het kabinet laat weten dat burgers geen grootse campagne om 'ja' te stemmen hoeven verwachten. De Haagse logica, tien jaar na het 'nee' tegen de Europese grondwet, is dat als de regering ergens voor pleit, dit weleens het tegengestelde effect kan sorteren. Het cynisme over nut en rol van de politiek is blijkbaar nergens groter dan onder politici zelf. Hoe groter de angst voor Wilders en 'de populisten', hoe geringer het zelfvertrouwen.", u' Dus ja, de burgers moeten het ditmaal helemaal zelf uitzoeken. Ten eerste zullen ze dus moeten besluiten of Poetins interventie in Oekra\xefne moet worden beloond. Hiervoor zijn verschillende drogredenen beschikbaar: er zijn grotere problemen, Oekra\xefne ligt eigenlijk toch in de Russische invloedssfeer, en als Poetin in Syri\xeb gerehabiliteerd wordt, waarom zouden we dan nog zo moeilijk doen over de Krim? En hebben we zelf ook niet Kosovo afgesnoept van Servi\xeb?', u' Ten tweede zullen ze, zelfs als ze hun opstelling eenmaal hebben bepaald, nog altijd voor het raadsel staan hoe ze hun mening het effectiefst kunnen uitdragen. Vooral als ze v\xf3\xf3r het associatieverdrag zijn. Want moet je dan gaan stemmen? Of juist niet, om de opkomst zo laag te houden dat niemand de uitslag serieus kan nemen?', u"In een interview met deze krant legde oud secretaris-generaal van de NAVO Jaap de Hoop Scheffer zich in november al neer bij de rehabilitatie van Poetin als leider op het wereldtoneel: Poetin is onmisbaar in Syri\xeb en de prijs die hij daarvoor gaat vragen is be\xebindiging van de sancties. En ja, mijmerde hij verder, de NAVO had 'handiger' kunnen optreden dan door vage toezeggingen te doen aan Oekra\xefne en Georgi\xeb in 2008. Beide landen kregen sindsdien te maken met een Russische inval.", u" Maar misschien is het toch nog iets te vroeg om door de knie\xebn te gaan. Poetins werkelijkheid is minder florissant dan vriend en vijand denken. Zijn buitenlandse avonturen worden met veel bravoure gepresenteerd, maar leveren nog zeer weinig op - behalve grote aantallen burgerslachtoffers. De economie glijdt snel af. Zelfs de 'strategische reserves' in de staatskas drogen in ijltempo op.", " De binnenlandse repressie heeft sinds Poetins terugkeer in 2012 vormen aangenomen die in het moderne Rusland ongekend zijn. De jacht op binnenlandse 'verraders' (lees: andersdenkenden) wordt afgekondigd in reusachtige banieren die zijn opgehangen langs centrale straten van Moskou - als een 21ste eeuwse uitvoering van George Orwells 1984.", u"Het bewind van president Poetin wordt in eigen land tegelijk breed gedragen en is efemeer. Hij is dankzij de oorlogsstemming voor het eerst sinds jaren weer \xe9cht populair, maar tegelijk klagen de mensen steen en been. De groep adviseurs die de besluitvorming kunnen be\xefnvloeden is enorm versmald. Gematigde economen zijn gedegradeerd. Op tv regeren priesters en malloten. Siloviki, de mannen uit de 'machtsministeries', lijken een monopolie op toegang tot Poetin te hebben.", " Deze heeft de afgelopen jaren zijn positie gered door te zwichten voor een verleiding die hij twaalf jaar weerstond: ongeremd Russisch nationalisme. De propaganda roept een beeld op alsof Rusland een herhaling beleeft van het beleg van Leningrad door de nazi's, terwijl Poetin zelf voedselimporten uit de halve wereld in de ban heeft gedaan. Nu de geest uit de fles is, krijgt niemand hem weer terug, ook de president zelf niet. Het was zijn ultieme wapen.", ' En hoe roekelozer president Poetin buiten de landsgrenzen optreedt, hoe minder vrienden hij er overhoudt. Zelfs bondgenoten Kazachstan en Wit-Rusland zoeken dekking en alternatieven. In plaats van een machtsblok met deze landen te vormen, zijn de grenscontroles tussen deze bondgenoten weer terug.', u"Al deze factoren maken de Poetin en het Rusland van 2016 veel onvoorspelbaarder, en daarmee riskanter, dan de Poetin en het Rusland van tien of zelfs vijf jaar geleden. In deze omstandigheden blijft de 'long game' - vasthouden aan beginselen, openstaan voor dialoog, uitgaan van eigen kracht en niet ingaan op militaire provocaties (zoals Turkije deed) - van het grootste belang. Voor Oekra\xefne en voor heel Europa.", ' Het lot wil dat Nederlandse burgers dit voorjaar een grote stem zullen hebben in de fundamentele uitdaging waarvoor Europa staat. Hopelijk graaft de Nederlandse burger zich niet in achter de dijk, maar klimt hij er juist op. All politics is local, maar deze tijd vraagt om een ver uitzicht.']
```